# Table of contents and appendices

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents, appendices

I am writing a "memoire" about a research project to end my undergraduate studies, but I am not able to format the sections and the table of contents as I would like to do. My paper, written with the LaTeX class article, is composed with 3 major sections, followed by 3 appendices and references at the end. I'd like it to have a table of contents looking like:

```
I- Section 1
II- Section 2
III- Section 3
Appendices
A - Appendix A
B - Appendix B
C - Appendix C
References
```

So far, I created a `\section{Appendices}` to make it have the same weight as the three first sections. But, as they are important and take several pages, I'd like each one of the appendices to be defined as a section too and not a subsection. Is there a way to make Appendices appear in the table of contents still showing that it contains the three following lines without defining it as a section. Sorry if I'm not really clear, and thank you in advance.

Also: I added the references with a `\begin{thebibliography}{99}` and they don't appear in the table of contents so far, how can I fix it?

Comment: Could you post the code snippet you've used so far?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always add a line like:

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{A}{Appendix A}}
```

and `section` gives the format you want. Then the level in the `toc` and the format of the heading is independent:

```
\newcounter{appendix}
\renewcommand\theappendix{\Aleph{appendix}}
\newenvironment{appendix}{%
    \refstepcounter{appendix}
    \subsection*{Appendix \theappendix}
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\protect\numberline{\theappendix}{Appendix \theappendix}}
}{}
```

I bet there's a package that does this too ;-) Also instead of using `\subsection` you could define your own heading with `\@startsection`. But that is more involved and probably not necessary.

As for the bibliography, if I understand you correctly, you can do it in the same way:

```
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\bibliography{mybibliography}
```